# deploying function app via AZ CLI fails with tooling error

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I have 2 different function apps and deployment scripts. The first app (functionApp1) uses the az cli, and the second one is being written to use the new AZ Powershell modules.

I thought I wouldn't be impacting the az cli solution by installing/setting up the latest powershell cmdlets but I think functionApp1's deployment is broken since installing the new Az Powershell tools.

When I run the az cli deployment script for function App 1, it dies while trying to publish the application.  The error message says:

> You're trying to use v4 tooling to publish to a non-v4 function app
> (FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION is set to ~3). You can pass --force to
> force update the app to v4, or downgrade tooling for publishing.

**Code**

In case it helps, here are some snippets of code from the deployment script for functionApp1 The following logic to create a resource group, application insights, and a storage account all works:

```
az login --service-principal --username $CLIENT_ID --password $SECRET --tenant $TENANT --allow-no-subscriptions

az account set --subscription $SUBSCRIPTION_ID

az group create -n $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME -l $RESOURCE_LOCATION

az deployment group create --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME --template-file (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "./resources/function1App.json")
```

Next I grab information from the new resources I created above, and I update my local.settings.json file. This also still works:

```
 func settings add FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME dotnet #explicitly set this.

 #auto-update the local.settings.json file with connection string
 func azure storage fetch-connection-string $storageAccount.name

 #grab contents of local settings file. 
 $data = Get-Content 'local.settings.json' -raw | ConvertFrom-Json

 #logic to update local settings.
```

Lastly I try to publish the functions in azure using my local settings file.  And this is the part that is no longer working:

```
$functionDeploymentResult = func azure functionapp publish $FUNCTION_APP.name --publish-local-settings -i --overwrite-settings -y
```

But the error message I'm getting is this:

```
 You're trying to use v4 tooling to publish to a non-v4 function app (FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION is set to ~3).
 You can pass --force to force update the app to v4, or downgrade tooling for publishing.
```

I tried to add the --force option and while it gets rid of the error message, when I try to actually run my test "hello world" function in azure, I see the following error message:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: One or more loaded extensions do not meet the minimum requirements. For more information see https://aka.ms/func-min-extension-versions.
ExtensionStartupType AzureStorageWebJobsStartup from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=asdfasdfasdf' does not meet the required minimum version of 4.0.4.0. Update your NuGet package reference for Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage to 4.0.4 or later.
```

**AZ CLI VERSION**

```
PS C:\Users\me\Documents\src\functionapp1> az --version

azure-cli                         2.30.0 *

core                              2.30.0 *
telemetry                          1.0.6

Python location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\python.exe'
Extensions directory 'C:\Users\me\.azure\cliextensions'

Python (Windows) 3.8.9 (tags/v3.8.9:a743f81, Apr  6 2021, 13:22:56) [MSC v.1928 32 bit (Intel)]

Legal docs and information: aka.ms/AzureCliLegal


You have 2 updates available. Consider updating your CLI installation with 'az upgrade'

Please let us know how we are doing: https://aka.ms/azureclihats
and let us know if you're interested in trying out our newest features: https://aka.ms/CLIUXstudy
```

**.vscode/settings.json**

```
{
  "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": "src/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish",
  "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "C#",
  "azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~3",
  "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
  "azureFunctions.preDeployTask": "publish (functions)"
}
```

I'm presently trying to do some research on how / what specifically to downgrade but any tips / suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Azure PowerShell does not interfere with Azure cli installation.
Based on the error message, it looks like the version of the Azure function tools you are using is v4 but the function app that you have deployed is v3 (likely defined so in the ARM template that you are using).